# How can I stop float left?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have the following code:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
  <label style="float: left;">ABC</label>  
  <input style="float: left; font-size: 0.5em;" type="button"   onclick="addTiny(0,'Question_Text'); return false;" value="&#x25BC;" title="Editor" />   
  <input style="float: left; font-size: 0.5em;" type="button" onclick="remTiny(0,'Question_Text'); return false;" value="&#x25B2;" title="Hide" />   

  <div class="adm">
    <textarea rows="2;" style="width: 100%" class="text-box multi-line mceEditor">
      abc
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the div with class adm floats to the left and so goes on the same line as the label and two input buttons. Is there a way that I can make this shift away from floating?

Comment: You should accept an answer, even if it's your own.

Answer (score 138):

A standard approach is to add a clearing div between the two floating block level elements:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: But in some cases you need to add `display:block`

Answer (score 76):

Sometimes clear will not work. Use `float: none` as an override

Comment: Yes, if you want to override an existing CSS entry `float: left` (or right) then this is the solution.

Answer (score 33):

You could modify `.adm` and add

```
.adm{
 clear:both;
}
```

That should make it move to a new line

Comment: That should be `.adm` I think.

Answer (score 11):

add `style="clear:both;"` to the "adm" `div`.

Answer (score 4):

Okay I just realized the answer is to remove the first float left from the first DIV. Don't know why I didn't see that before.

Answer (score 3):

You should also check out the "clear" property in css in case removing a float isn't an option

Answer (score 3):

The css `clear: left` in your adm class should stop the div floating with the elements above it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overflow:hidden` in the first `div` style. That should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason none of the above fixes worked for me (I had the same problem), but this did:

Try putting all of the floated elements in a div element:
`<div class="row">...</div>`.

Then add this CCS:
`.row::after {content: ""; clear: both; display: table;}`

Answer (score 0):

There's a class in bootstrap for it

`class="clearfix";`